# .bash_profile for root good practice?

Tags: bash, root

I rely on my `.bash_profile` for multiple aliases for script initiation as well as navigation.  This is not loaded under `su root`, so I was wondering if this is a good idea to create for root.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with creating a `profile` or `bashrc` for `root` - as long as you don't do anything nutty in them. `root` can benefit from *aliases* just as any other user -- unless you just like typing longer commands and directories when administering your box. Follow good `sudo` or `su/pam` practice and there is no reason not to create aliases for root in either file. If someone manages to get to your `root` profile or bashrc -- *aliases* are the least of your worries.

Answer (score 1):

`su root` is not a directory. It's a command to change the user ID associated with shell commands.

Anyways, there should be no danger in copying or symlinking your own `.bash_profile` to `/root` (the `root` user's `$HOME`, by default on most systems), as long as it does not contain any harmful commands that execute when the file is sourced.

As an aside, I would recommend moving things like bash aliases to `.bashrc`, not `.bash_profile`, as that is not what the `.bash_profile` is intended for.

Comment: Yes, I know.  As root, that's what I was asking.